# Stop google maps markers from having pointer cursor style on hover?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How can I stop my google maps markers from having the pointer cursor style on hover? Currently the markers behave like links in that if you hover the mouse over them the cursor changes to a hand.

Here is the code that creates the marker:

```js
function addMarkerLargeMap(latlng, myTitle, html, price) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map,
        title: myTitle, 
         icon: "path-to-my-icon.png",  
         html: "<div style='width:100px;height:auto'>" + html + "</div>",

      }));
```

Comment: may work marker.setCursor({cursor:'default'})

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Set clickable to false in the marker options

```js
function addMarkerLargeMap(latlng, myTitle, html, price) {
    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        clickable: false,
        map: map,
        title: myTitle, 
         icon: "path-to-my-icon.png",  
         html: "<div style='width:100px;height:auto'>" + html + "</div>",
      }));
```

Alternatively, you can set the `cursor` property in the marker options, if you want to use a specific type of cursor instead of the default.  e.g.

```js
cursor: 'crosshair'
```

Although this only seems to work if the marker *is* clickable.

Comment: Keep in mind that setting `clickable: false` will prevent the `title` (tooltip) from showing.

Answer (score 0):

`#main_map img {cursor:default!important;}`

Comment: Doest do anything. Ive also tried #map_canvas img as thats the ID of my map.

Comment: Is the `cursor:pointer` an inline style on the image? and do you have any other images that need the `cursor:pointer`? if not than you could just do `img { cursor:default!important; }`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 Reference. As of this date, 2022-08-22, [version 3.47](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.47) is the oldest for which documentation exists.

The [MarkerOptions interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker?hl=en) supports a `cursor` property. This supports any [CSS cursor property value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor). As I wanted to use the grabby-hand icon that is the default of the Google Map so that users know they can grab and drag the map around, I used `cursor: "grab"` in my `Marker` constructor options:

```
new google.maps.Marker({
  cursor: "grab",
  icon: "path-to-my-icon.png",
  map: map,
  position: latlng,
  title: myTitle
});
```